# Perl Net::SSH2 with thread crashing

Tags: multithreading, perl, ssh

I have a code like below. My problem is it is crashing in random basis with the following error:

```
perl: ath.c:193: _gcry_ath_mutex_lock: Assertion `*lock == ((ath_mutex_t) 0)' failed.
```

Like if I run the code 10 time it crashes 2-3 times. How to fix it?

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Net::SSH2;
use threads;

sub gsmExec {
    $host = $_[0];
    $port = $_[1];
    $user = $_[2];
    $pass = $_[3];
    my $modem = Net::SSH2->new();
    print "Trying to connect host $host : $port \n";
    if($modem->connect($host,$port)) {
        print "connected to host ..\n";

        if ($modem->auth_password($user,$password) {
            print "Authorized!!";
        }
    }
}

for(my $j = 1; $j <= $modemCount; $j++){
        $thrList[$j] = threads->create(\&gsmExec,'host',22,'user','pass');
}
```

Comment: That is probably caused by some bug in Net::SSH2 or in libssh2. The only solution is to find and fix it.

Comment: hmm.. I replaced threads by forks .. that solved my issue.

Comment: If you are going to run your script in a Linux/Unix box, you may like to use [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH)[::Parallel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH::Parallel) instead!

Comment: had the same problem with common-lisp,sbcl and libssh2. Using mutexes solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really a `perl` error there - that's a bit of C code within the `Net::SSH` library.

There are some indications that you aren't the only one to hit this problem:

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=936201

http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gcrypt-devel/2006-January/000910.html

It would appear there may be a bug in GnuTLS, which makes it not thread safe. 
Workarounds would be:

- single thread the 'TLS' bit.
- use `fork` instead of threading. (`Parallel::ForkManager` is pretty good for this).
- `Net::OpenSSH::Parallel` might also do the trick.